# Loading a video dataset (Keras)

Tags: python, tensorflow, video, keras

I'm trying to implement an LRCN/C(LSTM)RNN to classify emotions in videos. My dataset structure is split in two folders - "train_set" and "valid_set". 
When you open, either of them, you can find 3 folders, "positive", "negative" and "surprise". Lastly, each of these 3 folders has video-folders, each of which is a collection of frames of a video in .jpg. Videos have different length, hence a video-folder can have 200 frames, the one next to it 1200, 700...! To load the dataset I am using flow_from_directory. Here, I need a few clarifications:

1. Will in my case `flow_from_directory` load the videos 1 by 1, sequentially? Their frames?
2. If I load into batches, does `flow_from_directory` take a batch based on the sequential ordering of the images in a video?
3. If I have video_1 folder of 5 images and video_2 folder of 3 videos, and a batch size of 7, will `flow_from_directory` end up selecting two batches of 5 and 3 videos or it will overlap the videos, taking all 5 images from the first folder + 2 of the second? Will it mix my videos?
4. Is the dataset loading thread-safe? Worker one fetches video frames sequentially from folder 1, worker 2 from folder 2 etc... or each worker can takes frames from anywhere and any folder, which can spoil my sequential reading?
5. If I enable `shuffle`, will it shuffle the order in which it would read the video folders or it will start fetching frames in random order from random folders?
6. What does `TimeDisributed` layer do as from the documentation I cannot really imagine? What if I apply it to a CNN's dense layer or to each layer of a CNN?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. `flow_from_directory` is made for images, not movies. It will not understand your directory structure and will not create a "frames" dimension. You need your own generator (usually better to implement a [keras.utils.Sequence](https://keras.io/utils/))
2. You can only load into batches if :

   - you load movies one by one due to their different lengths
   - you pad your videos with empty frames to make them all have the same length
3. Same as 1.
4. If you make your own generator implementing a `keras.utils.Sequence()`, the safety will be kept as long as your implementation knows what is each movie.
5. It would shuffle images if you were loading images
6. `TimeDistributed` allows data with an extra dimension at index 1. Example: a layer that usually takes `(batch_size, ...other dims...)` will take `(batch_size, extra_dim, ...other dims...)`. This extra dimension may mean anything, not necessarily time, and it will remain untouched.

   - Recurrent layers don't need this (unless you really want an extra dimension there for unusual reasons), they already consider the index 1 as time.
   - CNNs will work exactly the same, for each image, but you can organize your data in the format `(batch_size, video_frames, height, width, channels)`

Comment: Thank you! Hence, If I am reading video frame, ofc, sequentially (assume batch size 1 for now), each frame gets classified by the CNN dense layer. Iteration 1 finishes, and the frame is fed into the RNN. At iteration 2, the second video frame runs through the CNN and the TimeDistributed now extends the output tensor in the time dimension to 2, making it point to time-step 2? Then that gets fed as a new step to the LSTM?
Is it ilke that, per iteration?
If so, does the CNN's dense re-input all its accumulated snapshots to the (in this case) RNN or it just passes the newest?

Comment: One batch should be `(1, frames, heght, width, channels)` in `TimeDistributed(Conv2D(...))`, or `(1, frames, features)` in `RNN` or `Dense`. There is no visible iteration, each layer will do it's job as it should. (Iterations happen invisibly inside the RNN regarding `frames`).

Comment: You can choose `return_sequences=True` in the RNNs to keep the frames until the end - The last layers will classify every frame. Or you may not choose that in the last RNN layer to eliminate the frames dimension and get "video classification".

Comment: lastly, does that mean, that my sequence generator should return to the CNN (batchsize, width, height, channels), where `batchsize' must be the number of frames I sequentially pass and after which to make a prediction?

Comment: As said in the answer, your shape should be `(batch, frames, height, width, channels)` for `TimeDistributed(Conv2D())` or `(batch, frames, allTheRest)` for RNNs and `Dense`.

Comment: Apologies, I have phrased my question poorly. The only thing I don't understand is what is the difference between `batch` and `frames`. A video is a sequence of images, in a folder. I've many folders, other people would, too. Does it then mean that, say, (batch=2, frames=11,...) would read 11 images from a folder and on every second batch of the images (after the 22ndread-in image) the error will be backpropagated? I need to understand that to write the generator properly, of course. :)

Comment: `batch = movies`, each movie is a sample/example. Unfortunately, there is no automatic folder reading. Keras doesn't have a standard generator for movies. You must control your folder structure and image loading yourself in a custom generator. So, it doesn't matter what your folder structure is, as long as you load and separate which frames belong to which movies.

Comment: PS: if there are people using standard generators for movies, I'd like to learn that :)

Comment: I have a last problem I cannot get over a day now. What should be the shape of the labels? As I fetch batches of 16 frames, I tried [16,], I tried [1,16], [1,1] and nothing works? :/
The errors I get: ```Input arrays should have the same number of samples as target arrays. Found 1 input samples and 16 target samples.``` [when 1,1]
```Error when checking target: expected dense_3 to have shape (1,) but got array with shape (16,)``` [when 1,16] Dense_3 is my output layer. They're sparsely encoded with ints from 0 to 2, as I have 3 classes.

Comment: It needs to be `(batch, ... more things ...)`. But what and "exactly how" do you want to extract information from the videos? The shape of the data is your goal. Single class? Multiclass? One classification per video? Classify every frame? Etc. Your choice. The model must obviously output accordingly after you decide.

Comment: Did you create the generator and have an example code of it?