# Preparing Video data for classification Keras

Tags: python, numpy, keras, deep-learning

I am unable to decide on feeding video data to the keras model. I'd like to use a DataGenerator for this case like ImageDataGenerator. From this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54005594/7576115) I gather,  ImageDataGenerator would not be suitable for this.

I have looked at this [github repo](https://github.com/jphdotam/keras_generator_example) for a VideoGenerator in keras which uses .npy files in directories. But the downside is, data augmentation is absent at the moment. How do I go about accomplishing this?

Is there no way I can use ImageDataGenerator?

Supposedly, I split all videos into frames and then load directories with .jpg files instead, how would that fare?

If I write a custom data generator using this [data generator tutorial](https://stanford.edu/~shervine/blog/keras-how-to-generate-data-on-the-fly), how do I arrange this partition dict? My data consists of .avi files.

Comment: What network do you intend to make, LRCN, LSTM?

Comment: I intend to make LSTM

Answer (score 0):

You might find this [example](https://pastebin.com/CPFQ64e6) helpful.
First you create your tensor of timestep data and then you reshape it for the LSTM network.

Assuming that your dataset consists of sorted frames in that order:

```
data/
    class0/
        img001.jpg
        img002.jpg
        ...
    class1/
        img001.jpg
        img002.jpg
        ...
```

Comment: the link seems to have been broken

Comment: Oh Yes, yesterday it was there. Anyway, i edited the answer.